# Where should I place data that will populate recyclerView items and its associated activity?

Tags: java, android

I am doing a running/exercise application and there will be a recyclerView that will show the user what runs they can do - when they click on an recylerView item it will take them to the "RunDetails" activity that will have textViews and imageViews with a description of the run, a picture, the scenery and recommended pace that will populate with different data depending on the recyclerView item clicked.

What is the best practice in where to store this information that will populate these recyclerView items and the dynamic activity that follows on? I don't have access to Cloud Storage, so I guess it will have to be local data on the phone.

Data will be text - a description of 15 - 20 words, a title of 2 words, and an image.

Thank you

Comment: what kind of data?

Answer (score 0):

Put your data in **resource folder**. Text data in *app/res/values/strings.xml* and images in *app/res/drawable*. Drawable contains folders: *drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xxxhdpi* to store scaled bitmaps (png, jpg) versions for different resolutions. Android will choose the right one based on device's screen.

For more details about how to work with these resources see  [Resource Types](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html).